# Exclude div from jQuery hover

Tags: jquery, google-maps, hover

As you can see on the following site, I have a div containing a google maps searchbox. I have set  jQuery hover functions on this div to show/hide it.
Hover and searchbox works but when I select an autocomplete result, the hover function on parent div thinks I moved my mouse out.

```
Site : http://81.64.185.202/new/
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: show the jquery script you wrote for this?

Comment: There is also warning reported: `Warning: you have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.` Better to fix it. You can merge them into one script link.

Comment: also share html of that portion as well

Answer (score 0):

Set your code like this

```
$( "panel" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).animate({"width": 500})
}, function() {
   $( this ).animate({"width": 50});
}
);
```